# Using application setting to save multiple values

Tags: c#, application-settings

I just want to know how to save two different values and using the application settings and use two different saved values. For example, i want to update the rate between USD to SGD and USD to MYR to 1.26 and 2.45 respectively. When i choose these conversion again, it should be 1.26 and 2.45 when it was saved as i press update button.

My Application settings:
[image: My Application settings]

```
//Form 1
private void exchange2()
    {
        string rate;
        string rate2;       


        if(fromcountry.Text == "USD - US Dollar" && tocountry.Text == "SGD - Singapore Dollar")
        {
            rate = Properties.Settings.Default.Rate;
            lblexchange.Text = rate;
        }
        else if (fromcountry.Text == "USD - US Dollar" && tocountry.Text == "MYR - Malaysian Ringgit")
        {
            rate2 = Properties.Settings.Default.Rate2;
            lblexchange.Text = rate2;
        }                
        else if (fromcountry.Text == tocountry.Text)
        {
            lblexchange.Text = "1";
        }

    }
//Form 2
private void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            double exchange;
            exchange = Double.Parse(txtcurrent.Text);

            var frm = (currencyconverter)this.Owner;
            frm.PassValue(txtcurrent.Text);

            Properties.Settings.Default.Rate = txtcurrent.Text;
            //How to settle the 2nd conversion?
            //Properties.Settings.Default.Rate2 = txtcurrent.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();       
            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Numbers", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtcurrent.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

On the code above, so far i can only save 1 of the values instead of 2 different values and that value overides the other. I'm totally stuck here and i need help. I can edit the question if its not clear.If application settings does not work to save multiple values, what are the methods that can do it?

Comment: You are assigning *both* settings in btnok_Click().  This is of course not a good idea, assign *one* of them.  You already know how to do that, see exchange2().

Comment: so.. what about the other?